# What does sql prepare get return?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, discord.js, better-sqlite3

When I do something like `sql.prepare("SELECT * FROM raid WHERE raid1 > 0 AND NOT id='685337576810610734'").run()`, does it return an array? How do I do this if I want to access each user independently who has raid1 > 0? Im not sure about the sql statement and Im not sure how to access each row individually one by one.

node.js

Answer (score 0):

-- For eg. Creating two variables to store two column values

'DECLARE @column1 int, @column2 nvarchar(50);

-- Declaring cursor

'DECLARE raid_cursor CURSOR FOR
'SELECT col1, col2 FROM raid WHERE raid1 > 0 AND NOT id='685337576810610734';

'OPEN raid_cursor
'FETCH NEXT FROM raid_cursor
'INTO @column1, @column2

'WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
'BEGIN
     -- Access each user individually
'END 
'CLOSE raid_cursor --close cursor

Comment: You can simply use CURSOR for accessing query records one by one.

Comment: Sorry for that. I was trying to explain on MS-SQL database. I can look on that.